# How do i get a session id of a Login Web-Application in my PHP web-page?

Tags: php, jsp

[image]**Tamper Data** gives all the cookie context i wish to automate that. `Session-Id` and `Login Credentials`.
`WGET` or `Wapiti` kinda stuff.. but these are cmnd line based ..
i wish a web-based one ! the Tamper data values i need to pass are under the red box of screenshot.

Comment: I suppose you want to get the values of the `request-headers`? If not can you provide a screen-shot of the tamper-data to show exactly what you want?
Thanks

Comment: yes, I want to fetch the values of request handlers to by-pass the actual login page by using one created by me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relying on the `request-header`'s values is dicey and it is flawed since the `request-header` values can be easily manipulated (one example is what you yourself are showing).

If you want to login automatically into another web-application using the credentials you have provided in some other web-application then you can use Single Sign-on (SSO). More info can be found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12454848/468763).

If you have some other requirement, then you can included that in the question so that it can be seen & answered accordingly.

Here is how you can get the request-header in a JSP:

1. `request.getHeader("cookie")` or `request.getHeader("user-agent")`.
2. Or can use: `request.getHeaderNames()` to get all the headers and then loop through the names and get each header value by using point#1 like this:

   ```
   Enumeration hNames = request.getHeaderNames();
   while(hNames.hasMoreElements()) {
       String hName = (String) hNames.nextElement();      
       System.out.println(hName + " = " + request.getHeader(hName);
   }
   ```
3. This link might be helpful: [Reading HTTP Request Headers](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/Servlet-Tutorial-Request-Headers.html)

Here is how you can get the request headers in PHP:

1. Nice answer to the question: [How do I read any request header in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/541430/468763),

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I wanted an alternative to SSO as i require the functionality on LAN only and no direct internet linkage is present.

Comment: I have edited my answer including how to fetch `request-headers`. Hope this helps.

Comment: those are certainly the links needed by me. Thanks again.